# .pkg installation when does authentication required is necessary?

Tags: macos, packagemaker

The question is about packagemaker and not the appstore based app.

I packaged a cocoa app via packagemaker to install on mac. PackageMaker has an option to require authentication from user while installing.

My questions is under what situations would 'authentication required' option be selected ? If this option is not checked which features will the app be unable to provide and vice-vera

Comment: without authentication i think you can only install to home directory and can't run any scripts

Answer (score 0):

If you want to install files in locations where write permissions are restricted for a normal user, you will have to check the '`authentication required`' option. It will result in the authentication dialog being displayed so that the installer can get the necessary authentication from the user and copy the files to those restricted locations using elevated privileges.
Examples:

```
1-Adding a launch daemon/agent. (Copied in /Library/LaunchAgents or /Library/LaunchDaemons)
2-Copying files to /Library/Application Support/
```

etc.

However, if your application only wants to install files, lets say in user's home directory, you don't have to ask for authentication.